# How to create empty EnumSet?

Tags: java, enumset

I am struggling with `EnumSet` as it surprisingly doesn't have a simple constructor and its methods doesn't like null values.

What I came up with:

```java
EnumSet<MyClass> x = EnumSet.copyOf(Collections.<MyClass>emptySet());
```

Which somewhat works but doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Use the method [`EnumSet.noneOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#noneOf(java.lang.Class)):

```java
EnumSet<MyClass> x = EnumSet.noneOf(MyClass.class);
```

Answer (score 32):

Use `EnumSet.noneOf(Class)` to create an empty EnumSet.